# Server GCM not starting when using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I created a javascript file (notification.js). I've used node.js to launch webservice in command ***node notification.js*** . And I get the error message ***Can not file module node-gcm***. I have previously downloaded node-gcm for node.js with command ***npm install node-gcm***.I do not know how to handle this. Please help me.

notification.js

```
var gcm = require('node-gcm');
//var gcm = require('../gcm.js');

var message = new gcm.Message();
var sender = new gcm.Sender('AIzaSyB8IAgyo9DJbmGiVISnCCoxcQRD7em6KfI');
var registrationIds = [];

message.addData('title','My Game');
message.addData('message','Your turn!!!!');
message.addData('msgcnt','1');
message.collapseKey = 'demo';
message.delayWhileIdle = true;
message.timeToLive = 3;

// At least one token is required - each app registers a different token
     registrationIds.push('APA91bHg7QEO3h44OCrBAb6yoHEvNvVSrRRcJjufS5fduCw2YhC83BZ9eqlxYS9PbKIAoFrmK-rvNEQ-CxrAjy4Wy13CRt5or1h7kG9XDRg2Tcy4zx8EpGOYLybmgnLDmVVvTJF4PR9Y');

server.listen(4040)
sender.send(message, registrationIds, 4, function (result) {
console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: My first debugging step would be to comment out everything except the first line - I assume you will still get the error, but would confirm that for yourself.  
Next do the "npm install node-gcm" in the same directory as notifification.js, and please paste the output into a comment here, as that will reveal if the npm install was successful or not  (if it was you should have a "node_modules" sub directory created).